# Connect to MS SQL Server on Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

I have been trying to connect to MS SQL Server from my Spring Boot Application but I have not been able to manage it yet.

Application.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://sqlsrv\\DESKTOP-ND9850L;databaseName=benjamin
spring.datasource.username=benjamin
spring.datasource.password=pass1234
```

Error Code.

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host sqlsrv, named instance desktop-nd9850l failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: sqlsrv". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434. For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server have you installed? What port is it configured to listen on - via SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager? Also, probably your computer name is `DESKTOP-ND9850L` so instead of `sqlsrv\\DESKTOP-ND9850L` you might want just `DESKTOP-ND9850L` or, if it's a named instance, `DESKTOP-ND9850L\\YourInstanceName`.

Comment: change the datasource.url line to : spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=benjamin

Comment: Hello @IssaKhodadadi here is the response after using localhost

The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.